# Как сделать анимация загрузки изображения?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Предположим есть `img` которого нету в кэше. Как в место анимации его загрузки браузером (сверху в низ) сделать анимацию: вместо изображения `ajax-loader.gif` а по его загрузке изображение появиться в блоке анимацией `.fadeIn()` из jQuery???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var image = new Image(); 
// важно добавить обработчик события до инициализации загрузки картинки
image.onload = function(){
   $('#img-tag')
      .css({'opacity':0, 'display':'none'})
      .attr('src', this.src)
      .fadeIn();
}
i.src = 'image.jpg'; // существующее изображение

<img src='loader.gif' id='img-tag'>
```

Comment: А полностью на jQuery как это выглядит?

Comment: $(new Image())
        .load(function () {
            $('#img-tag').hide().append(this).fadeIn();
        })
        .attr('src', 'image.jpg');

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет ли вот такой код?

```
$(document).on('load','img',function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

А ajax loader gif так и останется `background`'om к слою?

```
#img_div{
  background:url(ajax.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
img{
  opacity:0;
}
```

????

Comment: Если у вас работает, то подойдет.